# How can you safely convert an unsigned long int to an unsigned int?

Tags: c, assembly, riscv

I have some C code.  In it, I have a 64 bit value in the form of an unsigned long int.  I want to convert it into 2 different 32 bit values.  How can this be done safely?  Here is my first try:

```
char buff[16];
unsigned long int long_number;
unsigned int long_number_hi32;
unsigned int long_number_lw32;
long_number = 0x0123456789ABCDEFul;
long_number_hi32 = (unsigned int)(long_number >> 32);
long_number_lw32 = (unsigned int)(long_number >> 0);
kwrite("0x");
// This is a custom itoa function with params:
// (number (32-bit integer), buffer_ptr, buffer_length, base, pad_to_min_length)
itoa(long_number_hi32, buff, 16, 16, 8);
kwrite(buff);
itoa(long_number_lw32, buff, 16, 16, 8);
kwrite(buff);
kwrite("\n");
```

However the output I get is:

```
0x01234567FFFFFFFF89ABCDE
```

Inspecting the assembly, I find the problem:

```
LUI   a0,0x01234
ADDI  a0,a0,1383
# ...
# Call itoa
# Call kwrite
LUI   a0,0x89abd
ADDI  a0,a0,-529
# ...
# Call itoa
# Call kwrite
```

In 64-bit RISC-V assembly, LUI sign extends the provided 20-bit immediate value, setting the upper 32 bits of the destination register to whatever the 20th bit of the immediate was.  So, register a0 ends containing a value of 0xFFFFFFFF89ABCDEF.  I expect that my result was truncated at 'E' to prevent my buffer from overflowing, by putting the NULL terminator where my 'F' would have been.

I will add that my code does not look exactly like the example I provided because I have typedefed uint32_t, uint64_t, int32_t, and int64_t to the build in types of unsigned int, unsigned long int, signed int, and signed long int respectively.  I just substituted built-in types for the example.

How should this be done in C to that it is portability correct?  Do I have to use a union?  Are there other safe ways besides a union?

Comment: What does your `itoa` function do?  I suspect it is designed to work with *signed* integers.

Comment: ... and signed integers will tend to be sign-extended in cases where unsigned integers are not

Comment: I feel dumb.  You guys are correct.  I thought that I had coded the itoa function to treat the number as unsigned if it was given a base != 10.  But I wrote this itoa function over a year ago and forgot that it was actually conditional on the base being provided as a negative and was not even a finshed feature.  I was just looking over the source code for it.  Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @EchelonX-Ray No problem!  Stuff like that happens.

Comment: If I change the input parameter to take an unsigned integer, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Some problems:

**Insuffcient buffer**

To form a *string* like "FFFFFFFF89ABCDEF", `buff[]` needs 17.

```
// char buff[16];
char buff[17]; 
// itoa(long_number_lw32, buff, 16, 16, 8);
itoa(long_number_lw32, buff, sizeof buff, 16, 8);
```

---

**`unsigned` width**

`unsigned` may be 16 bit, 32, or more.

For this task consider widths *specified* at least 32.  `unsigned long, uint32least_t, uint32_t`.

```
// unsigned int long_number_lw32;
unsigned long long_number_lw32;

// long_number_lw32 = (unsigned int)(long_number >> 0);
long_number_lw32 = 0xFFFFFFFFu & long_number;
```

---

**`itoa()` for *unsigned*?**

I suspect `itoa()` is designed for an `int` result and risk [sign bit extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69396469/how-can-you-safely-convert-an-unsigned-long-int-to-an-unsigned-int/69397830#comment122657785_69396469).   Use a funciton that is designed for unsigned tpyes and at least 32-bit for this task.

---

**`long`: 32- or 64 bit?**

`long` may only be 32-bit.  Use a type that is specified to be wide enough. (at least 64)

```
// unsigned long int long_number;
unsigned long long long_number;
// long_number = 0x0123456789ABCDEFul;
long_number = 0x0123456789ABCDEFu; // l not needed
```